# How to use Python regex to select everything until pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

When I have an input like this

```
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต
เมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
ต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท
นายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ
```

my regex grabs

```
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
```

which is what I want. However when I have `[]` in the article text, it only grabs until the brackets. You can refer to it here `https://regex101.com/r/GMtEQS/2`

my current regex is `\[headline.*\/english[^\]]*][^\[$]*`

How do I select everything until the next `[headline`?

expected output

```
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has [] greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
```

Comment: Did any of the provided answers help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negated character class `[^\[$]*` does not match `[` or a `$`. Instead you can match the headlines between `[` and `]` and then match all lines that do not start with that pattern, matching all possible characters in between.

To match all the headlines that contain a https:// you could use

```
^\[headline\b[^][]*https?://[^][]*](?:\r?\n(?![\[headline]).*)*
```

**The pattern in parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `\[headline\b` Match opening `[` and `headline` followed by a word boundary
- `[^][]*https?://[^][]*` Match http with optional s and `://` between any char except `[` and `]`
- `]` Match the closing `]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?![\[headline]).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with `[headline`
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBbpGO/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ziTUpy)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^\[headline\b[^][]*https?://[^][]*](?:\r?\n(?![\[headline]).*)*"

s = ("[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]\n"
            "'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต\n"
            "เมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม\n"
            "[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]\n"
            "Here is some english text\n"
            "[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]\n"
            "Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.\n"
            "A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.\n"
            "[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]\n"
            "ต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท\n"
            "นายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ")

matches = re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
["[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]\n'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต\nเมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม", '[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]\nHere is some english text', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]\nForeigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.\nA protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]\nต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท\nนายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

If you change `[^\[$]*` to `[^$]*` to not match square bracket and add `(?=\[headline)` what means "match everything what is followed by `[headline`", so you'll get the expected output.

https://regex101.com/r/GMtEQS/3

The main issue - you'll never get the last block that way. I'm not sure how to overcome this.

https://regex101.com/r/GMtEQS/4

But we are using python, yes? What if use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)? Split the whole text by headlines and process every chunk in python.

main.py

```
import re

text = """[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต
เมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has [] greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
ต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท
นายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ"""

chunks = re.split(r'(\[headline - https:\/\/prachatai.com.*\])\n', text)

for i in range(1, len(chunks), 2):
    headline = chunks[i]
    body = chunks[i+1]
    if 'english' in headline:
        print(headline)
        print(body)
```

```
$ python3 main.py 
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text

[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has [] greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I did not think of solving it this way. The only reason why I used that was to ```re.sub(english_article_regex, "", all_articles, 0, re.MULTILINE)``` So I would eliminate the English texts and would only get non-english Thai text. How do I get the non-english ones, that has no ```enligh``` in their url?

Comment: also not all the URLS have ```prachatai.com``` so it wouldn't work for all headlines. Could you modify it for more general one? just for ```https://*```?